# understanding underscore.js: the _ object definition

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm reading [underscore.js sources](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), trying to understand all of it. The thing I don't yet understand is the definition of `_` object. It's source is:

```
var _ = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

In the actual scope (an iife), this refers to the global object and `_` has not yet been declared yet.

If you type `_` and hit enter in a console (e.g. chrome), assuming you've loaded underscore lib, you'll get the same function definition as above. Well - what is it for? Why isn't it just a normal object `{}` with all functions/attributes attached as properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underscore's `_` function is is meant to work as a wrapper around other objects, like arrays, it's not just a collection of methods.

It needs to do both this:

```
_.each(array, function () {...});
```

and this:

```
_(array).each(function () {...});
```